# Terminology of Verb Types in the present perfect such as (find vs break): found/have found it vs broke/have broken it

Tags: present-perfect, terminology

Usually there is a difference in meaning between the past simple and present perfect constructions.

However, in American English, ***found*** and ***have found*** do not exhibit much difference in the following scenario:
If you were looking for something and then just found it, you could say ***I found it*** or ***I have found it***. The default choice is for ***found it*** though.

In contrast, the verb *break*, I guess, does not show the same behavior in a similar scenario like above. ***Broke a leg*** for example is just past, history while ***have broken a leg*** always means the effect on the leg is still present; still broken.

If not, Americans would always recognize a big difference in meaning with other verbs. The present construction and the simple past are not interchangeable in the scenario above. The difference between the two forms is not about emphasis on recency, but about **past** and **present**.

I once came across a terminology used to classify verbs in the present perfect but I do not have any recollection of that. At any rate, linguists must have terminology when they study verbs in the context of present perfect. What is the terminology?

Comment: As a native speaker of AmE, I have to disagree, though I think this has nothing to do with AmE versus BrE. **Found** and **have found** do indeed have different meanings.  *Have broken a leg* does not always mean that the effect on the leg is still present  in the sense that healing is incomplete. The break could have happened in childhood and the sentence could be spoken by an elderly person. The present perfect expresses some relationship of the past event to the speaker's Present. That relationship varies.

Comment: Doctor talking to elderly person: Have you ever had a broken bone? Elderly person: Yes, I have broken a leg.  Doctor: When did that happen? Elderly person: When I was 11.

Comment: We can also vary intonation to convey distinctions. *I **have** drunk Polish vodka* would usually mean I've done this at least once in the (probably, *distant*) past, whereas *I've drunk Polish vodka* probably means I'm ***currently*** shitfaced.

Comment: I didn't mention the other uses for the present perfect. The one you both mentioned is used to talk about experiences in ESL grammar books. I guess I should edit the question to confine the contrast to only the uses I mentioned in the post. I once read a comment by @StoneyB about the term but I can't seem to remember anything about it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *I have drunk Polish vodka* would indeed mean I've done this at least once and don’t you think I've (anything)… is a straight contraction of *I have…*? How could it be otherwise?

Comment: Except in special circumstances, *Have broken a leg* does always mean the effect on the leg is still present. If the break happened in childhood and was later spoken of by the victim, grown elderly, then the appropriate phrase would be *I broke a leg*. The only way *I have broken a leg* could be appropriate would be not in an account of a single incident but in a list of life-time accomplishments: *I have done this and that, explored the other, loved women and fathered children, killed bad guys, saved a comrade, broken a leg, won three battles and lost a war…*

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin: In the context of my vodka example, it's misleading to say ***I've** is a straight contraction of **I have***. The whole *point* of the example is to show that intonation can affect meaning. I wrote ***have*** in bold to indicate that it's spoken with heavy stress - you can't do this with the contracted form, which is why ***I've** drunk Polish vodka* only really works with the "ongoing relevance" sense, not the "at least once in the past" sense.

Comment: Thanks and are you saying ***I have*** *drunk* is significantly different from *I've* ***drunk***, please?

Comment: Also… *found* and *have found* do exhibit much difference: If you were looking for something and then just found it, you could indeed say *I found it* or *I have found it* but that’s due to the particular scenario. 

Could you say *I found it at 3 o’clock*?

Could you say *I have found it at 3 o’clock*?

Simples…